# Checking if values of a form in a modal are empty

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

When the program starts a modal opens and I want it to disable a button within the modal if the 9 entries of the form are filled in but despite finding the button and the modal document.getElementById('pE').elements.item(n).value was returning as if it was not finding it.  I forget what I did to get the error to go away but now the code is not working.  the while loop is not running because when i removed the (document.getElementById("ManuSub").disabled = false;) the button did not go disabled but all of the other programs and functions I have program work.  What adjustment do I have to make to make this program work.

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var n = 0
  var formName = document.getElementById('pE')
        document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block"
  while((n<=9) && (formName.elements.item(n).value === undefined)){
   document.getElementById("ManuSub").disabled = true;
   for(n=0;n<9;n++){};
  }
  document.getElementById("ManuSub").disabled = false;
 }
```

Edit: I fixed my stated above issue I think with this code but now my program is not even loading which I believe is because of the while loop.

```js
window.onload = function(){
 document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block"
 var n = 0
 var formName = document.getElementById('pE')
 while(n<=8){
  setTimeout(5000,function(){if(formName.elements.item(n).value == '')        {
  document.getElementById("ManuSub").disabled = true;
  n=n+1
  }
  if(formName.elements.item(8).value == ''){
  n = 0
  }
 });
 
}
}
```

Comment: What are these two loops doing there? Don't you want a simple conditional (`if`-statement)`?

Comment: It needs to constantly check if the form boxes are filled/empty because I don't want the modal to close without the form containing information

Comment: That does not work. "Constantly checking" means hanging in an infinite loop, freezing the browser. Instead, you need to listen to the appropriate events and check the boxes *every time* an attempt to close the modal happens.

Comment: I'll do that instead what I wanted to do was disable the button but your way sounds way easier